# 00936. 00000 - "missing expression" when creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, view

When I run my script for the following View I get this error:

Error report - 
ORA-00936: missing expression 
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression" 
*Cause: 
*Action:

Script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mainUser.studentData_view
(
    StudentID,
    StudentName,
    StudentDOB,
    StudentSubjectID,
    SubjectName,
    LastUpdated)

AS
    SELECT student.StudentID,
           student.StudentName,
           student.StudentDOB,
           student.StudentSubjectID,
           subject.SubjectName,
           audit.SYSTIMESTAMP
    FROM   mainuser.studentdata student,
           mainuser.studentdatachanges audit,
           mainuser.subjectdata subject
    WHERE  student.StudentSubjectID = subject.SubjectID
           AND AUD.systimestamp = (SELECT Max(SYSTIMESTAMP)
                                   FROM   mainuser.studentdatachanges AUD2
                                   WHERE  AUD2.NEW_StudentID = AUD.new_studentid);
```

Comment: `aud` alias doesnt exist you have `audit` alias

Comment: Also missing a join predicate for the `aud`/`audit` table.  (ie. `AUD.studentID = student.StudentID`)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: `SYSTIMESTAMP` is also a [built-in function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions208.htm#SQLRF06125). It's a bad idea to name a column the same. `SELECT Max(SYSTIMESTAMP)` could easily be mis-read as the max of a constant value. You should at least write `SELECT Max(aud2.SYSTIMESTAMP)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use explicit join syntax (`JOIN` keywords), it makes everything clearer.  Your query with explicit joins looks like this:

```
SELECT ... --Removed to shorten query
FROM mainUser.studentData student
JOIN mainUser.studentDataChanges audit --Missing join predicate
JOIN mainUser.subjectData subject ON student.StudentSubjectID = subject.SubjectID
WHERE AUD.SYSTIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(SYSTIMESTAMP) 
                          FROM mainUser.studentDataChanges AUD2 
                          WHERE AUD2.NEW_StudentID = AUD.NEW_StudentID);
```

A few things to note here:

- `studentDataChanges` is aliased `audit` then referenced as `AUD`.  Need to pick one of the two
- `studentDataChanges` is missing a join predicate (maybe `AUD.StudentID = student.StudentID` ?)

It will look something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM mainUser.studentData student
JOIN mainUser.studentDataChanges AUD ON AUD.StudentID = student.StudentID 
JOIN mainUser.subjectData subject ON student.StudentSubjectID = subject.SubjectID
WHERE AUD.SYSTIMESTAMP = (SELECT MAX(SYSTIMESTAMP) 
                          FROM mainUser.studentDataChanges AUD2 
                          WHERE AUD2.NEW_StudentID = AUD.NEW_StudentID);
```